# Magento 1.7.0.0 FishPig - Excluding Category

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, fishpig

**EDIT 01-28-13: Revised to clarify my question.**

I'm using Magento 1.7.0.0 and FishPig WP full integration. We have successfully listed products from specific category and from all categories but was wondering if we can exclude in some cases from specified category. I found solutions to do this in functions.php within WordPress but this does not seem to work.

Here is the current code that displays posts from all categories. We'd like to add an exception so WordPress 1 Category can be excluded.

**Here is the code that displays from all categories which I'd like to NOT include category "Press_HomePage":**

```
    $col_posts = Mage::getResourceModel('wordpress/post_collection')->addIsPublishedFilter();
    $posttotal = count($col_posts->getAllIds());
    $posttotid = $col_posts->getAllIds();

    //i<=2 means displays last 2 posts
    //display latest 2 posts...
    for ( $i=1; $i<=2; $i++ )
      {
  ?>
        <div class="blog">
          <h2><?php echo $col_posts->getItemById($posttotid[$posttotal-$i])->getPostDate(); ?></h2>
          <h1><?php echo $col_posts->getItemById($posttotid[$posttotal-$i])->getPostTitle(); ?></h1>
          <div style="float:left; margin-top:15px; margin-bottom:25px;">
          <?php 
            $featured_img = $this->getSkinUrl('images/pree_emty.png');
            if($featuredImage = $col_posts->getItemById($posttotid[$posttotal-$i])->getFeaturedImage())
              {
                $featured_img = $featuredImage->getAvailableImage();
              }
          ?>
            <img style="float: left;" src="<?php echo $featured_img; ?>" width="204" height="204" alt="" />

            <div style="float: left; width: 580px; padding: 10px;">
              <p><?php echo substr(strip_tags($col_posts->getItemById($posttotid[$posttotal-$i])->getPostContent()), 0, 400); ?></p>
              <p>
                <a href="<?php echo $col_posts->getItemById($posttotid[$posttotal-$i])->getUrl(); ?>">
                  <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/view_btn.jpg'); ?>" width="170" height="32" alt="" />
                </a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
  <?php
      }
  ?>
```

Let me know if I need to clarify myself. I appreciate your time.

Comment: I am finding this a very confusing question.  I can't tell where you are referring to Magento categories and when it's Wordpress categories you are talking about.

Comment: The last block of code posted above where I say "Let me know if I need to clarify myself..." is where we need to exclude the category "Press_HomePage". I figured to wrap that code in the 2nd code block but it would seem that:

" $posts = $this->getPosts();
    echo count($posts);" is a WP only function which is why it always returns 0 posts outside of a FishPig template.

Comment: fyi, its all WordPress categories I'm referring to. The homepage devtest.eboost.com's press section at end of page reads from Category "Press_HomePage". Problem is that those posts from that category also show on "devtest.eboost.com page ->About->Our Blog".

Comment: OK, I've revised my question to help clarify. Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    //loki - get all the post ids
    $col_posts = Mage::getResourceModel('wordpress/post_collection')->addIsPublishedFilter();
    $posttotid = $col_posts->getAllIds();

    //loki - get all the press ids
    $col_posts_press = Mage::getResourceModel('wordpress/post_collection')->addIsPublishedFilter()->addCategorySlugFilter('press_homepage');
    $posttotid_press = $col_posts_press->getAllIds();

    //loki - removing the press_homepage category from array and reindexing
    $blogposts = array_diff($posttotid, $posttotid_press);
    $blogposts = array_values($blogposts);
    $posttotal = count($blogposts);

    //i<=2 means displays last 2 posts
    //display latest 2 posts...

    for ( $i=1; $i<=2; $i++ )
      {

  ?>
        <div class="blog">
          <h2><?php echo $col_posts->getItemById($blogposts[$posttotal-$i])->getPostDate(); ?></h2>
          <h1><?php echo $col_posts->getItemById($blogposts[$posttotal-$i])->getPostTitle(); ?></h1>
          <div style="float:left; margin-top:15px; margin-bottom:25px;">
          <?php 
            $featured_img = $this->getSkinUrl('images/pree_emty.png');
            if($featuredImage = $col_posts->getItemById($blogposts[$posttotal-$i])->getFeaturedImage())
              {
                $featured_img = $featuredImage->getAvailableImage();
              }
          ?>
            <img style="float: left;" src="<?php echo $featured_img; ?>" width="204" height="204" alt="" />

            <div style="float: left; width: 580px; padding: 10px;">
              <p><?php echo substr(strip_tags($col_posts->getItemById($blogposts[$posttotal-$i])->getPostContent()), 0, 400); ?></p>
              <p>
                <a href="<?php echo $col_posts->getItemById($blogposts[$posttotal-$i])->getUrl(); ?>">
                  <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/view_btn.jpg'); ?>" width="170" height="32" alt="" />
                </a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
  <?php
      }
  ?>
```